# osTicket uploading files with new ticket

Tags: php, upload

I'm trying to add a new field to the client side form for new tickets (staff side isn't necessary, but if it's all the same...) so that the user can upload a file.  I saw the "allow upload functionality" setting in the admin panel, so I believe this is possible.  I'm new to osTicket so please forgive me if this is obvious.

Which file should I be editing? Could you guys give me a clue?

Answer (score 1):

```
There are settings in backend of osticket just enable those ones
 step1- login to backend of osticket with admin privileges
 step2- click on tab settings(next to dashboard).
 step3- within settings click on tab tickets.
 step4- There is Attachment section on this page.enable checkbox in front of 
        **Allow Attachments,online web attachments** etc.
 step5- change other settings as per requirement also you can specify the required file   types like .jpg,.png along with .doc and .pdf.
step6- Save the changes.

 If you want more customization you can edit file here osticket/include/client/open.inc.php
```